# Java SimpleDateFormat ParseException pattern seems to match

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I have used  SimpleDateFormat to parse Strings into Dates many times in the past, but today I ran across an error that I cannot seem to see. 
I am parsing a csv, and I have this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("﻿yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(nextLine[0]);
```

I get this error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-06-17 21:43:17.493"
```

It looks to me like the format matches the string when referencing the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

am I missing something with SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Stupid suggestion, but what if you trim the String? `dateFormat.parse(nextLine[0].trim());`

Comment: Any way you can post a portion of your CSV, at least the offending portion?

Comment: What charset of CSV? [From doc: The format is locale independent and digits must be taken from the Basic Latin block of the Unicode standard.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is worng with your code. You just have invisible symbols at this line

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

You probably copied it from a PDF file or other source that inject that symbols into your text.

Try to copy it manually and it will be fine. It work for me after I done so.

Comment: Yep, I'll buy this. 1+